# How to move file to other server in Laravel using ftp and private key?

Tags: php, laravel, ftp, filesystems, private-key

i want to move file from my site to other server using ftp in laravel.

i put this setting in config/filesystem.php and its works

```html
 'ftp' => [
            'driver'   => 'ftp',
            'host'     => 'ftp.xxx.my',
            'username' => 'xxx',
            'password' => 'xxx',
            'root' => '/tess',
        ],
```

But my client ask to use private key only without password and username, so i changed my setting

```html
'ftp' => [
                'driver'   => 'ftp',
                'host'     => 'ftp.xxx.my',
               'privateKey' =>storage_path('app/public/key/momuat.ppk'),
                'root' => '/tess',
            ],
```

and i got error

```
Could not login with username: anonymous, host: 192.168.0.123
```

Please help me

Comment: use `sftp` as driver

Comment: yes, i already try it too, but how to writethe  root of private key file?
i try 'privateKey' => 'C:\xampp\htdocs\xx\xx\public\key\momuat.ppk', or 'privateKey' =>storage_path('app/public/key/momuat.ppk')